# Не могу пробиться к ./scripts/driver-select ath9k (Debian)

Tags: драйвер, debian, linux

В общем, compat-wireless забит в /usr/src/, ннужен ath9k. (su) ./scripts/driver-select ath9k отвечает отсутствием файла/каталога. Куда и как теперь make install?

Comment: Давай не будим истерить и сформулируем вопрос, прожуй и спроси)

Comment: Пакет драйверов скачан, установить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, как вы это делали, но все установки драйверов (в том числе и собранных руками) должны производиться через sudo:

```
sudo make install
```

А вот код компилировать можно и обычному юзеру.

Comment: make install? ммм, как мило. Не лезьте в Debian, а делайте make install в Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
./scripts/driver-select\ ath9k
```

Пробелы надо экранировать.